# Get rid of CMake CMP0063 warning

Tags: cmake, visibility, deprecation-warning

I continually get this issue when configure my CMake project:

> CMake Warning (dev) at examples/CMakeLists.txt:74 (ADD_EXECUTABLE):
>    Policy CMP0063 is not set: Honor visibility properties for all target
>    types.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0063" for policy details.  Use the
>    cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
>
> Target "Protonect" of type "EXECUTABLE" has the following visibility
>   properties set for CXX:
>
> ```
> CXX_VISIBILITY_PRESET
> VISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN
> ```
>
> For compatibility CMake is not honoring them for this target. This
>   warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

I know I want to call `cmake_policy(SET CMP0063 NEW)` - which I'm doing, but then I'm not sure how I'm supposed to use `add_executable(Protonect)`.

Answer (score 2):

These kind of [policy warnings](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/manual/cmake-policies.7.html) are introduced with new CMake versions when the behavior of CMake is changed. So this warning just says that you have to choose which behavior you want.

> When a new policy is introduced, newer CMake versions will begin to warn about the backward compatible behavior.

Those warnings normally detect when you use such kind of feature. In your case - policy [`CMP0063`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/policy/CMP0063.html) - I suspect that you have set [`ENABLE_EXPORTS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/prop_tgt/ENABLE_EXPORTS.html) for one of your library targets.

So - for your question which one you want - I would also recommend

```
cmake_policy(SET CMP0063 NEW)
```

Because `OLD` would only be for cases where you rely on that `CXX_VISIBILITY_PRESET` and `VISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN` properties are *not* honored for "sources may be compiled as part of static libraries or object libraries and then linked into a shared library later".

For more details `CXX_VISIBILITY_PRESET` and `VISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN` see also

- [`GENERATE_EXPORT_HEADER()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/module/GenerateExportHeader.html) macro
- [What is the CMake equivalent to "gcc -fvisibility=hidden" when controlling the exported symbol of a shared library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17080869/what-is-the-cmake-equivalent-to-gcc-fvisibility-hidden-when-controlling-the-e)