# CMake to produce -hidden-l (instead of -l) on macOS to hide export symbols?

Tags: macos, cmake, clang

My project imports an external dependency (that I cannot change) that in turn depends on another static library (JPEG). Because of the other dependencies in my project that also have (JPEG) dependency, I need that dynamic library to **not** have export symbols from the static library (JPEG). Dynamic libraries `CMakeLists.txt` uses `find_library(JPEG)` and adds it as `target_link_libraries(mydependency PUBLIC JPEG::JPEG)` and I don't have any other control over that.

What I want to achieve is CMake to produce a linker option `-hidden-ljpeg` instead of `-ljpeg` in the final command for that dynamic library. Is there an more or less *elegant* way to achieve that?

Comment: Perhaps the following might be helpful: [What is the CMake equivalent to "gcc -fvisibility=hidden" when controlling the exported symbol of a shared library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17080869/what-is-the-cmake-equivalent-to-gcc-fvisibility-hidden-when-controlling-the-e)

Comment: @BenA. Thanks for the suggestion! Sadly this works only if you're producing the library I call in question "external dependency", so that you can change it's CMakeLists.txt file. But I'm only consuming it, I cannot modify it's code.